# Refactor LINQ method to introduce Lamba function as a parameter

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, refactoring, expression

I have the current code, it uses LINQ to select validated ids from an id list:

```
var ids = idList
            .Select(page => page.PageId?? -1)
            .Where(id => id > -1)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();
```

In my application I use this code fragment a lot and I was wondering if I could wrap this piece of code in another function and pass the two lambda expressions as parameters to shorten it.

Something like:

```
int[] pageIds = getIdsOfPages(page => page.Id ?? -1, id => id > -1);
```

Could I implement this and How would I go about this?

I have seen lambda expressions and functions but I've had no luck so far. `Expression<Func<Object, Bool>>` & `Func<Object, Bool>`.

P.s the second parameter id > -1. That would be a constant.. only the first parameter would change.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

Here's my current implementation:
Calling method:

```
public int[] getPageIds(List<PageObject> pageHeadersList){

    IQueryable<DataModel.PageHeader> list = pageHeadersList.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();

    int[] pageIds = list.GetIds(x => x.PageId ?? -1);

    return pageIds;
}



public static IQueryable<T> ExecuteWhereClause<T>(IQueryable<T> inputQuery, string paramName, object typedValue)
{
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var condition =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                    Expression.GreaterThan(
                        Expression.Property(parameter, paramName),
                        Expression.Constant(typedValue)
                    ),
                    parameter
                );

        return inputQuery.Where(condition);
}


public static int[] GetIds<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{

        var newList = list.Select(keySelector)
             .AsQueryable();

        var newListAfterWhere = ExecuteWhereClause(newList , "Id", -1);

        return newListAfterWhere .Cast<int>().ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing the types involved. Please could you provide a [mcve] including what you've tried and the errors it creates?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the question to include current codebase

Comment: `public int[] getPageIds(pageHeadersList)` is not a valid method declaration. It's missing the type of the parameter, which is one of the most important aspects.

Comment: Hmm. Is there any particular reason you're using expression trees at all? I believe the code would be simpler if you stuck to delegates.

Comment: @JonSkeet First thing is that I've learnt that expression trees are really powerful, especially in combination with LINQ. I'm just exploring the possibilities of how to refactor such code too. That's why I'm using expression trees. There is a lot of delegate use in my code so far. Reducing this at any cost is a big win for my codebase.

Comment: Expression trees can be powerful *when you need them* but I don't see any indication that they're useful here. The purpose of expression trees is usually to allow other code to examine the tree to convert the query into a different form (e.g. SQL). You're not doing any of that here. I would strongly advise against habitually using expression trees without a specific reason to do so. You're making the code more complicated and probably less efficient that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the `Select` and the `Where` tell you what kind of input functions they need. The answer is already in your question post.

For `Where` you need

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> filter
```

and for `Select` :

```
Expression<Func<YourType, int>> selector
```

Here is an example with a custom class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int[] getIdsOfPages<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> list, Expression<Func<TSource, int>> select, Expression<Func<int, bool>> filter)
    {
        return list
            .Select(select)
            .Where(filter)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
int[] pageIds = idList.AsQueryable().getIdsOfPages(page => page.PageId ?? -1, id => id > -1);


public static List<MyClass> idList = new List<MyClass>();
public class MyClass
{
    public int? PageId { get; set; }
}
```

Although it looks for me to be more efficient, if you would first filter and then select. You would modify the selector function a little:

```
public static int[] getIdsOfPagesFilterFirst<TSource>(
                   this IQueryable<TSource> list, 
                   Expression<Func<TSource, int>> select, 
                   Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> filter)
{
    return list.Where(filter).Select(select).Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
int[] pageIds = idList.AsQueryable().getIdsOfPagesFilterFirst(page => page.PageId.Value , page => page.PageId.HasValue);
```

Comment: Hi Mong Zhu. Thank you for this answer. It's really clear and concise and it's helped me to get my head around the way you can pass lambda functions to methods as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I created earlier which allows Where, OrderBy and Select where T = YourClass

```
public IQueryable<T> Get(
    Expression<Func<T, int>> select,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> where,
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy)
{
    var databaseSet = this.Context.Set<T>();
    var query = (IQueryable<T>) databaseSet;
    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(where);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        query = orderBy(query);
    }

    if (select != null)
    {
         query = query.Select(select);
    }

    return query;
}
```